# Changing image of UIImage with time

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview

I want to change an UIImageView's image and 3 seconds later go back to the first image...This is my code:

```
-(void)change: (UIImageView *)sender
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNAmed: @"anImage"];
    [sender setImage:image];
    [self performSelector: @selector(doNothing) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
    [sender setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"firstImage"]];
}
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
-(void)change: (UIImageView *)sender
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNAmed: @"anImage"];
    [sender setImage:image];
    [sender performSelector: @selector(setImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed: @"firstImage"] afterDelay:3];
}
```

`performSelector` schedules selector call with some delay. It does not delay the execution of current method

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code for `doNothing` too please?

If `doNothing` really does nothing, then what's happening is the `doNothing` method is being called after 3 seconds from when the following line executes:

```
[self performSelector: @selector(doNothing) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

***But*** here's the thing, the following line is being executed straight after your `doNothing` method has been *scheduled* to run after three seconds:

```
[sender setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"firstImage"]];
```

In other words, the method execution doesn't wait around for your `doNothing` method to complete, it just continues, and `doNothing` is run on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

you have said to perform the function doNothing after 3 seconds of delay. So after 3 seconds it will get called so change the image back to firstImage in doNothing function.